# Unable to log in using my React app due to cross error

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, cross-domain, next-api

Unable to log in using my React app. I have created API endpoint using next js and trying to access that endpoint in react application.
My Api service is run at port number 3000 and my react app run on 8080 port that's why I got the Cross error.
I have tried lots of but am still stuck.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have tried already tried by added the header in server side like this.
`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'); res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');`

This is my API endpoint: http://localhost:3000/api/posts
and this is my react app in which I have used this endpoint to fetch the posts: http://localhost:8080/
using the some Chrome extension like CROS that fixes the issue
after enabling I got all the post and user details means get endpoint working  fine
but when trying to log in as user it is POST method not able log in still getting a CROSS error